# Parse Thai Name into First Last

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, string-parsing, thai

I need to parse a list of FullNames into First and Last Name.  If a middle name is included, it should be included in the fist name field.

**John Smith would be:**

> FirstName = John
>
> LastName = Smith

**John J. Smith would be:**

> FirstName = John J.
>
> LastName = Smith

The issue is the names might be either Thai or English character set.  I need to properly parse either set.  I have tried just about everything...

```
DECLARE @FullName NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'กล้วยไม้ สวามิวัศดุ์'
--DECLARE @FullName NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'Mark C. Wilson'

SELECT 
    LEN(@FullName) AS StringLength,
    LEN(@FullName) - LEN(REPLACE(@FullName,N' ', N'')),
    LEN(REPLACE(@FullName,N' ', N'')),
    @FullName AS FullName,
    REVERSE(@FullName) AS ReverseName, -- This is obviously no Reverse of the string
    CHARINDEX(N' ', REVERSE(@FullName)) AS LastSpaceLocation,
    CHARINDEX(N' ', @FullName) AS FirstSpaceLocation,
    LEN(@FullName) AS LenString,
    STUFF(@FullName, 1, CHARINDEX(N' ', @FullName), N'') as FirstName,
    RIGHT(@FullName, LEN(@FullName) - CHARINDEX(N' ', @FullName) + 1) as LastName,
    LEFT(@FullName, LEN(@FullName) - CHARINDEX(N' ', REVERSE(@FullName))) AS FirstName,
    STUFF(RIGHT(@FullName, CHARINDEX(N' ', REVERSE(@FullName))),1,1,N'') AS LastName,
    LEN(@FullName),
    REVERSE(@FullName),
    REVERSE(' '),
    LEN(@FullName) - CHARINDEX(reverse(' '), REVERSE(@FullName)) - LEN(' ') + 1
```

The `REVERSE` simply does not work when the Thai character set is used.

Comment: This happens because reversing the Thai name screws up the combining characters, which get "attached" to the space, causing a simple lexicographical search to fail. You can "fix" this, to some extent, by forcing a binary collation (`SELECT CHARINDEX(N' ', REVERSE(N'กล้วยไม้ สวามิวัศดุ์') COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN2)`), but you may well run into other oddities. Once you start branching out to more languages (like Japanese, or other languages with name components in an order different from English, or no last names at all) it'll only get harder. Consider leaving names alone where possible.

Comment: You seem to have [already asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53233664/sql-server-parsing-thai-language-full-name-to-first-last) this question, and the existing answer has demonstrated that your approach based on reversing strings is fundamentally flawed and should be revised. It is clear that you have improved the query since the time the original question was asked, but the question stays the same; so you may need editing the original Q instead of asking a new one. VTC/duplicate.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Server Parsing Thai Language Full Name to First Last](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53233664/sql-server-parsing-thai-language-full-name-to-first-last)

Comment: I saw this and it was not a valid solution for my issue.  Reverse() did not work properly with the character set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't read Thai (I'm not that bright), but perhaps this may help.

Here we are using a CROSS APPLY to "fix" the string, and then it is a small matter of `PasrName()` and `Concat()`

I should add, parsing names is a slippery slope.  One needs to consider

- Multi Word Last Names  ie De la Cruz
- Suffix  ie.  Richard R Cappelletti MD

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable table (FullName nvarchar(100))
Insert Into @YourTable values
 ('John Smith')
,('John J. Smith')
,(N'กล้วยไม้ สวามิวัศดุ์')

Select A.*
      ,LastName  = replace(parsename(S,1),'|','.')
      ,FirstName = replace(concat(parsename(S,4),' '+parsename(S,3),' '+parsename(S,2)),'|','.')
 From  @YourTable A
 Cross Apply ( values (replace(replace(FullName,'.','|'),' ','.'))) B(S)
```

**Returns**

```
FullName          LastName    FirstName
John Smith        Smith       John
John J. Smith     Smith       John J.
กล้วยไม้ สวามิวัศดุ์    สวามิวัศดุ์     กล้วยไม้
```

**EDIT 2008 Version**

```
Select A.*
      ,LastName  = replace(parsename(S,1),'|','.')
      ,FirstName = replace( IsNull(parsename(S,4),'') + IsNull(' '+parsename(S,3),'') + IsNull(' '+parsename(S,2),''),'|','.')
 From  @YourTable A
 Cross Apply ( values (replace(replace(FullName,'.','|'),' ','.'))) B(S)
```

Comment: I apologize, but unfortunately this is in a SS 2008 database.  I realize this is near end of life, but...  Anyway, concat was introduced in SQL Server 2012.

Comment: @Mark: Fortunately `CONCAT` is just a convenience in this case to deal with `NULL`s. Concatenating the strings with `+` and wrapping the concatenated expressions with `ISNULL(..., '')` will do to downgrade it.

Comment: @Mark Seed EDIT 2008 Version

Comment: @Mark Just saying ... Extended Support for 2008 ends July 2019.  Please tag your questions with 2008 to avoid assumptions.

Answer (score 1):

I'm Thai and one thing I know is that Thai people don't do middle name.

Comment: Fun Fact ... The no middle name thing

Comment: I'm Dutch and I have two of them. I never mention them because I don't expect any code to get it right, least of all database code. :-)